# Setting screen name dynamically in channel forms

Tags: channel-form, screen-name

Is there a way to set the "screen name" dynamically for a member via `{exp:channel:forms}`?

I only see `dynamic_title` parameter. Is there a way to do this for screen name?

Comment: Are you trying to modify a member's screen name via a channel form?

Comment: @StephenCallender Yup, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in the [**channel:forms docs**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#form-inputs) that you can set screen_name with this tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anna. I asked this question here precisely because it is not something you see in the docs.